# Ubuntu server burn in test

Tags: ubuntu, stress-testing

We've assembled a simple storage server with COTS SATA disks that we're planning to tie together with software raid (Ubuntu Server, mdadm). What burn-in tests can one run to test the system, in particular the disks since they're brand new?

Answer (score 1):

Use DriveStress to test the drives. See: http://www.roylongbottom.org.uk/linux%20burn-in%20apps.htm#anchor7 for more info